# add string to array with keeping object type

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question about an array of php.

I want to add a string to array.

**below is example.**

```
**the $color variable has like below object.**

array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color' => string 'dbbbbb' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color' => string 'dbbbbb' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color' => string 'dbbbbb' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color' => string 'dbbbbb' (length=6)
```

I want to append an string with keeping object like,

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color' => string '#dbbbbb' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color' => string '#dbbbbb' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color' => string '#dbbbbb' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color' => string '#dbbbbb' (length=6)
```

yes, simply wanna append **'#'** character.

I tried many ways to **implode** on foreach and so. but but couldn't do it as prefix.

You guys have any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_walk()` to modify every element in an array:

```
$color = [...]; // your array
array_walk($color, function(&$element, $key_not_used) {
    $element['color'] = '#' . $element['color'];
});
```

Note that you are actually walking through the outer array and changing the value at the `color` key on the inner arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` loop with to accomplish this:

```
foreach ($color as & $c) {
    $c['color'] = '#'.$c['color'];
}

print_r($color);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81530)

Comment: If `$color` is the outer array this will actually not work.  As this is a nested array and `$item` would be an array.  You would be trying to concatenate a string to that inner array element.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Ah. you're right. I'm bad at reading var_dump outputs ^_^